# Get the value of span tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a HTML `<table>`, I succeed to iterate it using this code :

```
var rows = document.querySelectorAll("#ff\\:tablereparation tr"); 
for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    alert(rows[i].cells[0].innerHTML);
    alert(rows[i].cells[1].innerHTML); 
}
```

The problem is  I had a result with a `<span>` tag :

```
<span id="ff:tablereparation:0:np">Panne grave</span>
```

I want just the value, in this case :`Panne grave`, I tried with `value`,`text()`,`val()` but it didn't work.

Comment: Try `.textContent` instead of `.innerHTML`. If you have multiple elements within, the try `element.querySelector('span').textContent`

Comment: @Rajesh thank you,it works  with `.textContent`

Comment: `span` doesn't have "value", you mean get its innerHTML

Comment: show us your code. what you put isn't enough. make a demo in `jsbin` or something

Comment: So is `ff:tablereparation` supposed to be the `ID` of the table or the span because the HTML you have showing here isn't matching the selector. Is the table inside of your span tag? Your selector is targeting `ID` `ff:tablereparation` and then all `td` tags within that. In that order.... Also if you have multiple elements with this `ID` you should know that `ID`'s are supposed to be unique so a `class` name should be used.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you should do :

```
var rows = document.querySelectorAll("#ff\\:tablereparation tr"); 
for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
        alert(rows[i].cells[j].textContent);
    }
}
```

See [**this Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/f9ex2v8v/5/) for a demo.